# WordPress | enqueue_scripts in a child's theme returns error

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-script

I intended to load a script within a child's theme because I wanted to experiment with a feature.
Initially, I loaded the script as follows:

```
// loading menu toggle function
function menu_toggle_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'menu-toggle', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/menu.js');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'menu_toggle_enqueue_script');
```

Unfortunately, that returned an error.

Comment: What error? Please be as specific as possible.

Answer (score -1):

The reason being that:

`get_template_directory_uri()` actually returns the **parent's theme** url.

To fix it, I simply concatenated the remainder of the path. In this case, the code became:

```
// loading menu toggle function | located in the child's theme folder
function menu_toggle_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'menu-toggle', get_template_directory_uri(). '-child' . '/assets/js/menu.js');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'menu_toggle_enqueue_script');
```

I figured out the solution on my own and thought I would share it since I did not find this solution anywhere I researched.

Comment: (You've also managed to post this answer using a different account with the same name. You can [get them merged](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for the future.)

Comment: @Rup Better yet, use `get_theme_file_uri()`.